# Why is my global variable not working?

Tags: javascript

The content variable even with a window in front of it, is not known to the second function that tries to use it. What am I doing wrong?

```
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction();">Button</div>

function MyFunction(){
window.content = "Hello";    
chi();
}

function chi() {
var MyNewVar = content;    
alert(MyNewVar);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DN3yC/10/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DN3yC/11/ works fine, select No wrap-in<body>

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong? "* You are using `onLoad` instead of `no wrap` in jsFiddle.

Comment: Here : http://jsfiddle.net/DN3yC/21/
Wrap the js in head or body tags

Comment: Also, you have defined MyFunction, but are calling myFunction. JavaScript variables are case-sensitive.

Comment: @Jay - In the fiddle, yes, the casing is consistent. The code sample posted has different casing for the function definition and the function call.